# Everything is in utf8, but text isn't recording correctly to db anyway

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

I've created a database (with utf8 charset) and a table with the same charset, all the rows are utf8, in webpage I have meta tag for utf8... But anyway, when I type in my forms smth not in latin alphabet, it registers in db wth eg. Ñ„Ñ‹Ð²Ñ„Ñ‹Ð
Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use such code after connecting to DataBase, but befor you recieve/write data

```
$db->query('set character_set_client=utf8');
$db->query('set character_set_connection=utf8');
$db->query('set character_set_results=utf8');
$db->query('set character_set_server=utf8');
```